# how do i compile multiple jade files

Tags: node.js, pug

let's start off with the following 4 jade files.

layout.jade

```
html
    head
        block cms_head
    body
        block cms_body
```

home_page.jade

```
extends layout
block append cms_head
    title home page
block append cms_body
    p superman ate so many different apples
```

plugin_a.jade

```
block append cms_body
    p i got plugged in... genius
```

plugin_for_jquery.jade

```
block append cms_head
    script(src="/jquery-1.8.3.js")
```

so i can easily render the home page by doing:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home_page");
});
```

which is fantastic, however in order to allow for plugability in my app, i would like to allow their views to take advantage of existing templates, and append/prepend/replace content to whatever the plugin needs to show.

what i am trying to do is render home_page.jade, then render plugin_a.jade and plugin_for_jquery.jade ... the basic idea is there can be a variable number of plugins, and each plugin adding it's own content to the view.

I tried this (obviously it didn't work)

```
for plugin in plugins
    include= plugin.name
```

So any ideas on how i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i know there is no possability in jade to readout the directory

but using node:

```
var fs = require("fs");   

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    fs.readdir(DIR_OF_PLUGINS, function(err, list){
        res.render("home_page", {"list": list});
    });
});
```

and in homepage.jade

```
- for(plugin in list)
   include = plugin
```

btw: you should build a router and a functions document with something like

```
//router.js // or app.js
var funct = require("routes/functions")
app.get('/', funct.home);

//functions.js
exports.home = function(req, res){
```